# presenting UIAlertController from a toolbar button

Tags: ios8, uialertcontroller

Dumb question - but how do I present an UIAlertController (popover) from a toolbar button? Previously (with UIAlertView) I'd simply call showFromBarButtonItem: but this doesn't appear to be possible with the UIAlertController.

I have a workaround - as below - but it's a bit 'risky'

```
    UIView* senderView = [sender valueForKey:@"view"]; //HACK
    UIPopoverPresentationController* popover = alertController.popoverPresentationController;
    if (popover)
    {
        popover.sourceView = senderView;
        popover.sourceRect = senderView.bounds;
        popover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
    }
```

(sender is a UIBarButtonItem)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to set`popover.barButtonItem`